# Long commit results in slow performance of nHibernate

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

We're using nHibernate in an ASP web application with the session-per-request pattern. Some actions which the user is able to do, result in several hundreds of INSERT and UPDATE statements which takes several seconds to complete. This results in a bad performance as the user does not get to see the result of his actions until the entire transaction is committed to the database.

By the way, previously we saved the result in the Session but this is not a good solution either. Writing stuff to the Session results in a read-write lock and thus in concurrent requests being handled in sequence. A long request thus blocks other requests until its done. That's why we switched to writing the result to the database, but as I explained, this comes with its own set of problems.

How can we approach this problem? I can only think of somehow sending the result bakc to the browser while the results are being committed in the background. If that's possible, I wouldn't know how as the sessions is coupled to the request from the browser. But maybe it is possible? Or are there solutions that would work?

**EDIT**

- we're using Guid.Comb identifier strategy
- to give an idea of the size of the commit: a single commit involves over 2000 INSERT and UPDATE statements and during the run of the operation a similar amount of SELECT statements is issued. The commit takes 2-4 minutes to complete (is that long?).

Please ask if I haven't provided sufficient information. I don't really know what would be interesting to write here at this moment as I have no clue in what direction I should be looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote about this problem here:

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/09/the-benefits-of-letting-the-orm-generate-the-identity-part-1/

If you're using `IDENTITY` or `GUID`s that are generated in the database, you're going to suffer from slow inserts and the inability to batch.

When inserting into SQL using a GUID, NHibernate issues a request to get a new GUID first.

You end up with a transaction like so:

```
- statement #1
begin transaction with isolation level: Unspecified

- statement #2
select newid()

- statement #3
select newid()

- statement #4
select newid()

- statement #5
INSERT INTO Fruit
            (Name,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Apple0' /* @p0_0 */,
             '269bc638-74b4-4568-85d1-45b6e537fcbd' /* @p1_0 */)

INSERT INTO Fruit
            (Name,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Apple1' /* @p0_1 */,
             'fc848779-b173-4c31-b8b6-0a7735c0c2dc' /* @p1_1 */)

INSERT INTO Fruit
            (Name,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Apple2' /* @p0_2 */,
             '232c8971-18c7-486d-9152-26c969c3b632' /* @p1_2 */)

- statement #6
commit transaction
```

Likewise when you use IDENTITY, NHibernate needs to select the new Id back out of the database to update the model, this is especially important when NHibernate needs to relate this new object to another before inserting.

Using IDENTITY ends up with a transaction looking like:

```
- statement #1
begin transaction with isolation level: Unspecified

- statement #2
INSERT INTO People
            (FirstName,
             Surname)
VALUES      ('Phillip0' /* @p0 */,
             'Haydon' /* @p1 */);

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

- statement #3
INSERT INTO People
            (FirstName,
             Surname)
VALUES      ('Phillip1' /* @p0 */,
             'Haydon' /* @p1 */);

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

- statement #4
INSERT INTO People
            (FirstName,
             Surname)
VALUES      ('Phillip2' /* @p0 */,
             'Haydon' /* @p1 */);

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

- statement #5
commit transaction
```

Running some basic tests on a pretty decent computer I got insert results with timings of the following:

- IDENTITY 28951ms
- NEWID 30241ms

Updating this to use HiLo or GuidComb, allows NHibernate to generate the identities itself.

Using HiLo, NHibernate will issue a request for the next hi value, then update the hi value, once having a hi it can generate a range of Ids until the lo is full.

This results in an insert like so:

```
- statement #1
begin transaction with isolation level: Unspecified

- statement #2
Reading high value: 
select next_hi
from   hibernate_unique_key with (updlock, rowlock)

- statement #3
Updating high value: 
update hibernate_unique_key
set    next_hi = 3 /* @p0 */
where  next_hi = 2 /* @p1 */

- statement #4
INSERT INTO People
            (FirstName,
             Surname,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Phillip0' /* @p0_0 */,
             'Haydon' /* @p1_0 */,
             202 /* @p2_0 */)

INSERT INTO People
            (FirstName,
             Surname,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Phillip1' /* @p0_1 */,
             'Haydon' /* @p1_1 */,
             203 /* @p2_1 */)

INSERT INTO People
            (FirstName,
             Surname,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Phillip2' /* @p0_2 */,
             'Haydon' /* @p1_2 */,
             204 /* @p2_2 */)

- statement #5
commit transaction
```

Likewise using GuidComb, NHibernate will generate a GUID for you:

```
- statement #1
begin transaction with isolation level: Unspecified

- statement #2
INSERT INTO Fruit
            (Name,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Apple0' /* @p0_0 */,
             'db902160-edbb-49c7-bf52-9f660018299a' /* @p1_0 */)

INSERT INTO Fruit
            (Name,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Apple1' /* @p0_1 */,
             '5e852528-3a6f-41d2-a6b1-9f660018299a' /* @p1_1 */)

INSERT INTO Fruit
            (Name,
             Id)
VALUES      ('Apple2' /* @p0_2 */,
             '2f63c6e8-e595-4393-ad15-9f660018299a' /* @p1_2 */)

- statement #3
commit transaction
```

This means NHibernate doesn't need to round-trip to the database when doing inserts, both these allow bulk inserts to occur, as you can see in both HiLo and GuidComb, only 1 statement is sent to the server, unlike NEWID / IDENTITY where a statement is sent for each insert, or a select for each new id is made.

This results in a much lower time like:

- HiLo 9287ms
- GuidComb 9060ms

I hope that helps :)

Comment: We're already using GuidComb, so that's not something we can improve on.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code, but in most cases you can get better performance you using batches in NHibernate. Setting a larger batch size, will result in less roundtrips to the database. However you may have to rewrite some code.

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">1000</property>
```

Will configure your batch size.

Any second option is to use a IStatelessSession instead of a ISession. You do not have any state, abeit the performance can improve.

Comment: Setting the batchsize that large would also affect the retrieval performance negatively I think. And statelesssessions are not an option in this case, because that would mean we lose the cascades which are the bulk of the INSERT and UPDATE statements.